# How to add a single point to a lineChart in iOS-charts

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, ios-charts

I have a lineChart and I want to add a single point (scattered point).
Is that possible?
Is there any workaround?
I tried to figure it out by to me seems impossible since even using scatter data only I have to use the same `xVals` array, and in my case the line has some `xVals` points and the single scattered point only one value on X and one on Y.

Thanks

EDIT:
This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

To me the only solution using iOS-charts is to superimpose two view charts...

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for truncating the line chart? I am not clear what's your question. If you just want scatter chart + line chart, use `CombinedChartView`.

I had a feature request for truncating line chart, so we can have 'single point' in the line chart, so if you don't want to connect the dots. Check if it is https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/280. If true, you could help comment so the author will know it.

On your side, what you can try is to subclass the line chart renderer and protocol to allow you add single dots. For me, I want to truncate the line if the current dot cannot be connected to the next one. such as y values: 1-2-3 5(single dot) 7-8-9.

You have to provide what you want so I can help you better.

For your ask in comment, I can only provide a few code get you started, but you have to fully understand what am I trying to do.

Knowledge you must have: CoreGraphics + CGAffineTransform (iOS), viewPortHandler, transformer, axisRenderer (ios-charts).

In my problem, I will subclass ScatterChartView, so I can draw xAxis like yAxis. The idea is to disable xAxis, and let rightAxis to be HorizontalBarChartYAxisRenderer acting as xAxis.

First, subclass ScatterChartView and override initialize():

```
public override func initialize() {
    super.initialize();
    doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false;
    xAxis.enabled = false;

    // to determine how much space left for the dots to be drawn

    _leftYAxisRenderer = ChartYAxisRenderer(viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler, yAxis: _leftAxis, transformer: _leftAxisTransformer);

    // right axis will be the bottom axis above xAxis
    _rightAxisTransformer = ChartTransformerHorizontalBarChart(viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler);
    _rightYAxisRenderer = MyChartYAxisRendererHorizontalBarChart(viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler, yAxis: _rightAxis, transformer: _rightAxisTransformer);

    renderer = MyScatterChartRenderer(delegate: self, animator: _animator, viewPortHandler: _viewPortHandler);
}
```

override prepareValuePxMatrix

```
internal override func prepareValuePxMatrix()
{
    // replace the chartXMin and deltaX with rightAxis values to keep the CTM correct
    _rightAxisTransformer.prepareMatrixValuePx(chartXMin: _rightAxis.axisMinimum, deltaX: CGFloat(_rightAxis.axisRange), deltaY: CGFloat(_leftAxis.axisRange), chartYMin: _leftAxis.axisMinimum);
    _leftAxisTransformer.prepareMatrixValuePx(chartXMin: _rightAxis.axisMinimum, deltaX: CGFloat(_rightAxis.axisRange), deltaY: CGFloat(_leftAxis.axisRange), chartYMin: _leftAxis.axisMinimum);
}
```

Until now, you have create the rightAxis acting as xAxis, and generate its matrix.

Now for the data part, I will create two dataSets, and assign them to AxisDependencyLeft and AxisDependencyRight via dataSet.axisDependency, so I can know how to render them.

In the chart renderer, I will read the two dataSets, one for x and one for y, and utilize the transformer to get the postion to draw.

such as:

```
    var xDataSet = scatterData.getRight()
    var yDataSet = scatterData.getLeft()
    var dataSet = yDataSet as! ScatterChartDataSet

    var trans = delegate!.scatterChartRenderer(self, transformerForAxis: dataSet.axisDependency)

    var phaseX = _animator.phaseX
    var phaseY = _animator.phaseY

    var xEntries = (xDataSet as! ScatterChartDataSet).yVals
    var entries = dataSet.yVals
    // if count not equal, something goes off
    if (xEntries.count != entries.count)
    {
        return
    }

    var shapeSize = dataSet.scatterShapeSize
    var shapeHalf = shapeSize / 2.0

    var point = CGPoint()

    var valueToPixelMatrix = trans.valueToPixelMatrix

    var shape = dataSet.scatterShape

    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    for (var j = 0, count = Int(min(ceil(CGFloat(entries.count) * _animator.phaseX), CGFloat(entries.count))); j < count; j++)
    {
        var e = entries[j]
        var xEntry = xEntries[j]
        point.x = CGFloat(xEntry.value)
        point.y = CGFloat(e.value) * phaseY
        point = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(point, valueToPixelMatrix)
        // now you have the point to render, such as:
        if (shape == .Circle)
        {
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, dataSet.colorAt(j).CGColor)
            var rect = CGRect()
            rect.origin.x = point.x - shapeHalf
            rect.origin.y = point.y - shapeHalf
            rect.size.width = shapeSize
            rect.size.height = shapeSize
            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)
        }
    }
```

I cannot provide all the code I have. You have to understand what am I doing, so you can imagine yours. The only magic is you get a chance to define how you want to render it.

Comment: I think that combined is my case. The only problem is that the line chart does not have the same x-values as the scatter one.

Comment: what you mean by that? you only need to add X values into combined chart data. take a look at demo

Comment: If you look at the demo the points of the line chart have the same x-values of the bar charts...do you have an example that do otherwise?

Comment: I still don't understand your question. If you are using combined chart view, you only need to set xValues to CombinedChartData, and use the same xValues as xIndex for your LineChartDataSet and ScatterChartDataSet, but you don't need to set xValues for LineChartData and ScattterChartData.

Comment: that's the point! I have to use the same xvalues! I don't want to do that! Look at the edit

Comment: Got you. Unfortunately, current scheme is using xIndex to draw the chart, so you don't get a chance. You question I have filed a issue long time ago:https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/176 and https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/194. The key is that we should draw the xAxis the same way as yAxis. On your side, If you are familiar with CoreGraphics and ios-charts details, you can replace the xAxis renderer with something like HorizontalBarChartYAxisRenderer, and then you can continue your customization.

Comment: However, you have to be quite familiar with ios-charts and the transformers to customize your xAxis renderer. If you aren't, maybe create two views and put them together would be easier for you.

Comment: just solved using a superimposition. I'll soon post the solution just in case one needs.

Comment: can you send me your solution? even superimposing is not enough because xAxis does not work as yAxis, I don't understand why they made this choice!

Comment: it's kind of hard to explain, I could give you some code samples, but you have to figure out your own, because mine just solve my problems

Comment: Please send me I'll try to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: see the answer editted. If you feel useful, then you owe me a beer! :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I preferred to change library since the present seems a bit limited. I moved to this https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts which is modular and more complete to my purposes. The documentation is quite weak but the support by the developer is excellent.